# How to plot gamma distribution for a dataframe in python

Tags: python, plot, seaborn, gamma-distribution, gamma

I have a population dataframe. How to plot a gamma distribution diagram?

I am using python and I can plot a diagram using seaborn or plot bar. But I need a gamma distribution diagram. I dont know how to fit my parameters into gamma functions.

```
plot = sns.distplot(df["Percent"])
fig = plot.get_figure()

plot2 = rows['state'].value_counts().plot.bar()
fig2 = plot2.get_figure()
```

It only shows me two general diagrams. Not sure how to get gamma distribution.

Comment: are you trying to plot a CDF or PDF of gamma distribution only or are you trying to plot some data in a histogram that you think is distributed like gamma?

Comment: Hi, I m not sure actually. I wish to get two gamma distribution diagrams of actual population and sample population distribution from data. Then to use K-L divergence to get the best sample that most close to the actual population.

Comment: Well, I think you need to figure out clearly what you intend to plot.  If you are plotting a large set of sample data, you want to plot a histogram, which can be done a bunch of ways.  It does not make sense to say you want to plot a gamma distribution of the data.  You only get to plot the data, not plot it as a particular distribution.  If you are done fitting a distribution to data, then once you have parameters and a CDF function, you can put a bunch of points into that to plot it.

Comment: Hi, could you help me? My input is a list of values and I need to get Generalized gamma distribution of the list. I need PDF instead of CDF.

Comment: Well, I still think we are x-wired on terms.  Why do you think the data is gamma-distributed?

The first thing you should do is plot a histogram of the data to see what it looks like.  Use matplotlib.  It should be close to a 1-liner to plot & show a histogram of a list.  If you then want to try to fit a distribution to the data, that is a different beast.

Comment: I am not sure if I need to plot a histogram. I got a list of actual population distribution and a list of sample population distribution. These are all observed data. My supervisor required me to transfer these into gamma distribution and then calculate the kl divergence value between two list.